# Is this mapping based solution correct?

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math

> A step starting at a point P in the XY -plane consists of moving by
> one unit from P in one of three directions: directly to the right or
> in the direction of one of the two rays that make the angle of ±120
> with positive X-axis. (An opposite move, i.e. to the
> left/southeast/northeast, is not allowed.) A path consists of a number
> of such steps, each new step starting where the previous step ended.
> Points and steps in a path may repeat. Find the number of paths
> starting at (1,0) and ending at (2,0) that consist of (i) exactly 6
> steps (ii) exactly 7 steps.

Let us consider a 2D grid large enough to cover the maximum traversal in any direction, in this case, 11 x 11 would suffice.

Let us number the rows from 0 to 10 and the columns from 0 to 10.
For $\displaystyle ( i,\ j)$ let us map the 2D array to a 1D array using $\displaystyle ( i,\ j) \ \rightarrow \ 10i\ +\ ( j\ +\ 1)$
Moving 1 unit along +120$^\circ$ is equivalent to reducing the current number by 12 and along -120$^\circ$ is equivalent to increasing the current number by 10.

Our source is at 56 and we need to reach 57.
And the base equation (governing the moves) is
$\displaystyle 10x\ -\ 12y\ +\ z\ =\ 1$
For case (i) requiring exactly 6 moves $\displaystyle x\ +\ y\ +\ z\ =\ 6$ and for case (ii) $\displaystyle x\ +\ y\ +\ z\ =\ 7$

z y and x are integers whose values can be 0 to 6.

[image: the table]

The picture shows the table in the solution.

Now my specific queries are

1. Are the equations obtained by me correct for the given problem?
2. Can someone suggest the best way to solve the 2 equations in each case?

Question Source : 2016 CMI B.Sc Entrance Examination Part A

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning of $-12$ and $+10$. An alternative way would be to use the third roots of unity

Comment: If you take a 2D grid of dimensions 11 x 11 using row and column indices 0 to 10, and for each cell you assign a number 10 times row index + column index + 1, compare the diagonal movements in the 2D grid to that in the 1D array obtained thus, the differences are therefore 12 and 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given legal $n$-step path from the point $(1,0)$ to the point $(2,0)$,

- Let $a$ be the number of unit steps to the right.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $b$ be the number of unit steps of the $+120^\circ$ type.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $c$ be the number of unit steps of the $-120^\circ$ type.

Then $a,b,c$ are nonnegative integers satisfying the equations
$$
\begin{cases}
a-{\large{\frac{b}{2}}}-{\large{\frac{c}{2}}}=1&\bigl(\,\text{based on the $x$-coordinates}\,\bigr)\\[4pt]                                                                                                                                   
b-c=0&\bigl(\,\text{based on the $y$-coordinates}\,\bigr)\\[4pt]                                                                                                                                   
a+b+c=n&\bigl(\,\text{based on the total number of steps}\,\bigr)\\
\end{cases}
$$
Solving the system yields
$$
(a,b,c)
=
\Bigl(
{\small{\frac{n+2}{3}}},\,
{\small{\frac{n-1}{3}}},\,
{\small{\frac{n-1}{3}}}
\Bigr)
$$
hence, given the integrality constraints, we must have $n\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;3)$.

Thus there are no legal $6$-step paths from the point $(1,0)$ to the point $(2,0)$.

For $n=7$ we have $(a,b,c)=(3,2,2)$, hence, noting that a path depends not just on $a,b,c$ but also on the order in which the types of steps are applied, it follows that there are
$$
\frac{7!}{3!2!2!}
=
210
$$
legal $7$-step paths from the point $(1,0)$ to the point $(2,0)$.

Comment: can you explain why you have used b/2 and c/2?

Comment: @Aritro Shome: The unit vectors in the $\pm 120^\circ$ directions have $x$-coordinate equal to $-{\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$.